# Removes duplicate from table and add the value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I have a cart table which looks like but I want to remove the duplicate product and add the price

my sql query is this:

```
$query = mysql_query("select product.productname, product.price, order.quantity
from product inner join order on product.productid = order.productid");
```

and here is my php code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $total = $row['quantity']*$row['quantity'];
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['productname'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$total.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

Product Name     Quantity      Unit Price       Total Price
Egg              12            6                72
Milk             2             30               60
Bread            5             5                25
Egg              3             6                18
Milk             5             30               150
```

I want to add the quantity and total price of the same product and the table should look like this

```
Product Name     Quantity      Unit Price       Total Price
Egg              15            6                90
Milk             7             30               210
Bread            5             5                25
```

How would I get the 2nd table result? should I change my query?

Comment: What is this `mysql_query("product.productname, product.price, order.quantity, 
from product inner join order on product.productid = order.productid");` ? Does your query had fulfilled?

Comment: sorry it's just a typo error, I edited it already

Comment: EDIT: solved, I used sum and group by function in my query               select product.productname, product.price, sum(order.quantity) as totalQuantity from product inner joinorder ON product.productid = order.productid group by productname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are wanting to GROUP BY your "Product Name" column. Look into the GROUP BY clause and SUM() aggregation function in the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

I think if you play around with SUM() and GROUP BY you'll get the hang of aggregating sets of data.